# How to draw graph of Gauss function?

Tags: plot, numerical-methods, maxima, piecewise

[Gauss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kuzmin%E2%80%93Wirsing_operator#The_Gaus_map) has an infinite number of jump discontinuities at x = 1/n, for positive integers.

I want to draw diagram of Gauss function.

Using Maxima cas I can draw it with simple command :

```
  f(x):= 1/x - floor(1/x);  plot2d(f(x),[x,0,1]);
```

[image]

but the result is not good ( near x=0 it should be like [here](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/publications/organic/figure1.ps))

Also Maxima claims:

`plot2d: expression evaluates to non-numeric value somewhere in plotting 
   range.`

I can define picewise function ( jump discontinuities at x = 1/n, for positive integers )

so I tried :

```
define( g(x), for i:2 thru 20 step 1 do if (x=i) then x else (1/x) - floor(1/x));
```

but it don't works.

I can also use chebyshew polynomials to aproximate function ( like in :  A Graduate Introduction to Numerical Methods From the Viewpoint of Backward Error Analysis by Corless, Robert, Fillion, Nicolas)

How to do it properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a list of segments with ending points. The result is : [image]

and full code is [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gauss_function.svg)

Edit: smaller size with shorter lists in case of almost straight lines,

if (n>20) then iMax:10 else iMax : 250,

in the GivePart function

Answer (score 4):

For `plot2d` you can set the `adapt_depth` and `nticks` parameters. The default values are 5 and 29, respectively. `set_plot_option()` (i.e. with no argument) returns the current list of option values. If you increase `adapt_depth` and/or `nticks`, then `plot2d` will use more points for plotting. Perhaps that makes the figure look good enough.

Another way is to use the `draw2d` function (in the `draw` package) and explicitly tell it to plot each segment. We know that there are discontinuities at 1/k, for k = 1, 2, 3, .... We have to decide how many segments to plot. Let's say 20.

```
(%i6) load (draw) $
(%i7) f(x):= 1/x - floor(1/x) $
(%i8) makelist (explicit (f, x, 1/(k + 1), 1/k), k, 1, 20);
(%o8) [explicit(f,x,1/2,1),explicit(f,x,1/3,1/2),
       explicit(f,x,1/4,1/3),explicit(f,x,1/5,1/4),
       explicit(f,x,1/6,1/5),explicit(f,x,1/7,1/6),
       explicit(f,x,1/8,1/7),explicit(f,x,1/9,1/8),
       explicit(f,x,1/10,1/9),explicit(f,x,1/11,1/10),
       explicit(f,x,1/12,1/11),explicit(f,x,1/13,1/12),
       explicit(f,x,1/14,1/13),explicit(f,x,1/15,1/14),
       explicit(f,x,1/16,1/15),explicit(f,x,1/17,1/16),
       explicit(f,x,1/18,1/17),explicit(f,x,1/19,1/18),
       explicit(f,x,1/20,1/19),explicit(f,x,1/21,1/20)]
(%i9) apply (draw2d, %);
```

Comment: Great. It works better. What about endpoints of the subdomains , like : https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Upper_semi.svg

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `draw2d(explicit(x^2, x, -2, 1), explicit(3 - (x - 2)^2, x, 1, 4))` draws the figure to which you linked. That's just using the same approach I showed above -- multiple `explicit` expressions in one `draw2d`.

Comment: I have made new image , see below.